# Why is the Bitcoin Wiki protected against editing?

Tags: bitcoin-wiki

I recently found an [error](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/IP_Transactions) on the [Bitcoin Wiki](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Main_Page), when I noticed that I could not edit it.

I made an account a long time ago, so I logged into it, but still I am not able to edit pages.

Why is this? A wiki is supposed to be community-driven.

Who does have access to the wiki pages?

Comment: try [This Wiki](http://bitcoinwiki.org) bitcoinwiki.org
The have still open edition

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To prevent vandalism and spam. You can gain edit access by [making a payment](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/BitcoinPayment) (in bitcoins, of course).

The payment required is (at least) 0.001 BTC, which is actually no longer trivially small in my opinion.

> BitcoinPayment is a MediaWiki extension to limit spam, by requiring a
>   small one-time bitcoin payment before a user is allowed to edit or
>   create pages.
>
> While the payment is deliberately trivially small for a normal user,
>   it presents a barrier to a mass-spammer.
>
> Funds sent to this wiki will be used to keep the wiki online (cost of
>   domain name and hosting), and remaining funds will be donated to the
>   Bitcoin Foundation.

Comment: I prefer a captcha.

Comment: It's probably a good idea to let people know about this when they click the edit button.

Comment: Note that the payment system for unlocking is both outdated (0.01 BTC is not a trivial amount anymore) and defunct (it used MtGox as payment processopr). I believe it is being worked on (as of march 2014) but don't know the state.

Comment: You can also get edit rights by coming to IRC channel #bitcoin-wiki on Freenode, ask  and stay there until someone adds you to the editors stay.